# How can I load a TTree with TVector3 branches into a Pandas DataFrame using uproot

Tags: uproot

I have several ROOT files containing a TTree with (among others) some branches that are TVector3 objects. I am trying to load the vector components (x, y, z) into a Pandas DataFrame, but I keep getting this error, no matter what I try:

```
ValueError: cannot interpret branch b'hitPosExtrap' as a Python type
```

I am trying to use `uproot.pandas.iterate`, but also tried with the tree's `f[tree_name].array('hitPosExtrap')` method to no avail. Reading the uproot README it looked to me as if it would be able to understand TVector3 objects, but but I guess I am missing something.

Does anyone know a way for me to get the vector components (or some TVector3-like objects) out of these trees?

Comment: TVector3 ought to work (it's not very different from TLorentzVector). Could you post a small file showing this error on the uproot GitHub Issues?

Comment: I created an issue here: https://github.com/scikit-hep/uproot/issues/443

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be that the TVector3 is stored as a subbranch in this particular root file. The vector components are accessible as leaves of that subbranch:

```
f[tree_name]["hitPosExtrap"]["fX"].array()
f[tree_name]["hitPosExtrap"]["fY"].array()
f[tree_name]["hitPosExtrap"]["fZ"].array()
```

After some discussion (https://github.com/scikit-hep/uproot/issues/443) it seems like uproot does currently not directly support providing the names of branches+subbranches when using the `pandas.iterate` function. For now one has to access the subbranches explicitly.